# Listing the elements of the subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a minor calculation mistake here.

I am asked to list the elements of subgroups $\langle 3\rangle$ in $U(20)$

So I write $U(20)= \{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$

$\langle 3\rangle = \{3,6,9,12,15,18,21\}$

Should the answer be $\{3,9,1\}$? The answers show there should be a $7$, but I don't know why.

Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $3\times 7=1 \pmod {20}$

Comment: why do you multiply 3 by 7 tho? @janmarqz

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: You make a mistake in the understanding of what $\langle 3 \rangle$ means: you assume it means the multiples of $3$, when in reality it means the powers of $3$: $1, 3, 9, 27, 81 \dots$. Of course, this sequence ends, because the group is finite. You mistakenly use addition as the group operation, when in reality you are supposed to use multiplication.

Comment: your own suggested answer works on the basis of addition (!). The group $U(20)$ has *multiplication* as its group operation.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you :)

Comment: @JennieDurham Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $3$, we get $3^2 = 9$ in the group. Then $3^3 = 27 = 7 \mod 20$. So $7$ is in the group as well. Then $3^4 = 3 \times 7 = 21 = 1 \mod 20$, so we are at the identity and we get nothing new by new powers of 3 (just 3 again etc.).

So $\{1, 3, 7, 9\}$ is the correct answer, the different powers of 3. This is how you compute the group (cyclic) generated by 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused between the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/20$ and the multiplicative group $U(20)$. To determine the group generated by $3$ in the *multiplicative* group, you need to look at successive powers of $3$ which, as Henno computed in another answer, is $\{3, 3^2 = 9, 3^3 = 27\equiv 7, 3^4 = 81\equiv 1\}$.